# Is there an idiom for something that will never happen?

Tags: idioms

Inspired by [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/436987) on English SE, and the [List of idioms of improbability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_idioms_of_improbability) in Wikipedia which does not have an entry for Japanese, I was wondering... Is there an idiom in Japanese for something that will never happen?

Answer (score 0):

This one is not strictly 'never', but it does indicate very low probability:

瓢箪から駒 (ひょうたん　から　こま)   a horse from a gourd

Answer (score 0):

This one's in [jisho.org](http://jisho.org/word/%E7%99%BE%E5%B9%B4%E6%B2%B3%E6%B8%85) with the definition of "when pigs fly", which is one of the English idioms that means the same thing:

百年河清【ひゃくねんかせい】を待つ -> Waiting a hundred years for the Yellow River to clear